# Good fit, but poor residuals in GAM

Tags: self-study, model-selection, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I am very new to GAM. Data represent: Weight loss ~ Days after treatment measured in two groups: A (black dots) and B (red dots). I magage to get an excellent fit, and yet I get what looks like a poor QQ plot of residuals. I am not sure how to proceed from here, I tried several smoothing functions but it doesn't seem to improve whatsoever. I do not know how to fix this...Importantly, should I fix it (deviance of residuals seems very small)?

```
# example ds
Y = c(0.160864, 0.156382, NA, NA, 0.148860, 0.146762, 
       0.144716, 0.142974, 0.141066, NA, NA, 0.136498, NA,
      NA, NA, 0.131464, NA,NA, 0.127264,  NA, NA, 0.148393, 
      0.144836, 0.141993, 0.139560, 0.137086, NA, NA, 
      0.131511, NA, NA, NA, 0.126056, NA, NA, 0.121831, NA, 
      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
X = c(rep(0:20, 2))
R = factor(c(rep("A", 21), rep("B", 21)))
ds <- data.frame(Y = Y, X = X, R = R)

#mydata
plot(Y~X, data = ds, pch = 19, col = R)
```

[image: my data]

```
library(mgcv)

# gam
md <- gam(Y ~ s(X) + R, data = ds)

# model checks
summary.gam(md)

Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
Y ~ s(X) + R

Parametric coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.1455444  0.0001272 1144.01  < 2e-16 ***
RB          -0.0114603  0.0002045  -56.05 8.01e-14 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
       edf Ref.df    F p-value    
s(X) 6.004  7.014 1565  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.999   Deviance explained = 99.9%
GCV = 2.5693e-07  Scale est. = 1.4268e-07  n = 18


gratia::appraise(md)
```

[image: model checks]

```
gratia::draw(md)
```

[image: model fit]

Comment: You might say you are using `mgcv` as there are other packages with `gam`

Comment: You have got very small residuals which appear to not be normally distributed.  So perhaps your model is missing something which is not particularly substantial.  Why do you care?

Comment: @Henry So, if I got it right, you mean that the scale matters. Care to elaborate a bit more? (I will update my question including: "SHOULD i fix it?" to allow your reaply as an answer)

Comment: Can you explain what the data are (in the question rather than in the comments)? What does the color in the graph signify? The relationships look almost deterministic with very little noise which is why you get such a good fit with small residuals.

Comment: `mgcv` uses reduced rank approach with automatic smoothing parameter selection. Does it help to choose smoothing function?

Comment: The relationship looks almost deterministic (indeed, $R^2 = 0.999$). With respect to the QQ plot, I am wondering if it is due to how it is computed. How it is computed seems to be determined by the argument "method" in the function appraise. The default is method = "uniform". I reproduced your example, just switching to method = "normal". The QQ plot makes more sense, with the two points on the extreme of the tail outside the confidence band. So my first guess is due to how the qq plot is computed. I recommend searching for the source code of the function.